# Accidentally replaced the partition table using GParted in UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

This machine has UBUNTU & wINDOWS XP. I'm currently logged into UBUNTU. I was just checking the features of GParted and accidentally clicked `Device > Create Partition Table`. A default MS-DOS partition table is created. Now if I re-start the Gparted there is nothing. Its showing entire disk as UNALLOCATED space.

Lucky thing is All the drives (C:, D:, E:) are currently mounted and I'm in UBUNTU. I guess its possible to re-create the partition table using current status.

But I don't know how? Can any one kindly tell me how to do this. This is a lab computer. If its not recoverable. I'm completely screwed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a lab machine, there may be identical machines with identical partition tables.

Run **fdisk -l** (as root) on similar systems and see if there is a consensus of partition table layout.

If you can duplicate the original partition table, there is a good chance for complete recovery. You may need to reload grub2.

Run **df -kT** and write down or print (I'm talking paper, dead trees) the sizes and order of partitions on the system. This will help you identify whether another system's partition table layout is similar or identical.

Comment: No, this system is a special(High end) system allocated to me. I'm trying testdisk. I think I may be able to recover the partition table using this.

Comment: There seem to be several partition table fixers on the web, however I don't have experience with any of them. I have used TestDisk for user data recovery, and can recommend it for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with programs that scans the whole hard disk to find the start of file systems (no names pop into my head now, but I know there exists such tools).

I wrote a partition table printing program several years ago called [printpar](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/utils/disk-management/printpar-1.1.3.zip); it contains a file `docs/recovery.txt` which has a short list of programs that tries to find partition tables on the hard disk. Note that this probably is *very* dated, but maybe it still is useful or can give you pointers to other information. You can also check out the list of recovery tools [here](http://www.freebyte.com/filediskutils/#datarecovery).

Answer (score 0):

Use methods from this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
**I have used testdisk from this link and it works for me.**
If You recreate partition table using fdisk it also may work but if You do it in exactrly correct way ( as i was before).

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)